# Using Drupal 8: Changing blog hyperlink sentences

Tags: drupal, module, blogs, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'm currently using Drupal 8 blog module, however I want to change some of the English that is used.

For example, "View recent blog entries"
"USERNAME's blog"

Is it possible to change this?

Or do you know a module I can use to do this?

Many thanks, 
Jake

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRi7S.png)

SOLVED:[Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsgG4.png)

Comment: Yes.You can do a search in which core/external module that is written.Otherwise, you can attach a screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks very much, I added a screenshot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understanding, There will be a blog module.Which was in the list of core modules before drupal-8 but now it has been removed.

**Note: Do following changes in blog.module file (Expected Path in root director of drupal:  /modules/blog/blog.module**)

Search this line :

```
$internal_link = \Drupal::l(t('View recent blog entries'), $url);
```

Replace with this line :

```
$internal_link = \Drupal::l(t($account->getUsername().'\'s Blog'), $url);
```

If Unable to see changes then do **clear all cache**.

Output Snippet : [image: Demo]

Comment: @jake66 Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked!
Added a screenshot of the change!